# Mapstruct Java 17 gives error in test cases when running via IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, mapstruct, java-17

Recently upgraded my code to java 17. Earlier I was using MapStruct 1.3.1 with Java 11.

So, let me tell/show you the three scenarios.

---

### **SCENARIO 1**

So now after java 17 update when I run my test case (say `MyTestMethod`) with the run button in IntelliJ

[image]

It throws this error -

> java: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor' less than -source '17'

---

### **SCENARIO 2**

But if I run the same test case with this command -

```
mvn test -Dtest="MyTestClass#MyTestMethod"
```

Its a **SUCCESS**

---

### **SCENARIO 3**

However If I change the version of MapStruct to 1.5.5.final **SCENARIO 1** starts working correctly.

---

**My questions now** -

1. Do I need to upgrade to 1.5.5.final, if so is there anything I should change in my code too to adhere to java 17 - mapstruct compatibility?
2. Why **SCENARIO 1** starts working when I change the version from 1.3.1.final to 1.5.5.final as mentioned in **SCENARIO 3** ?

Comment: which language level do you have in module's pom, and in project settings for project and for module? looks like maven runs different java comparing to IDEA